# A convenient way to plot bar-plot in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame contains as following, where first row is the "columns":

```
id,year,type,sale  
1,1998,a,5  
2,2000,b,10  
3,1999,c,20  
4,2001,b,15  
5,2001,a,25  
6,1998,b,5  
...
```

I want to draw two figures, the first one is like

[image]

The second one is like

[image]

Figures in my draft might not be in right scale. I am a newbie to Python and I understand plotting functionality is powerful in Python. I believe there must be very easy to plot such figures.

Comment: I like your scribbly charts... do you have any code for it :)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org) provides simple and efficient tools to analyze and plot DataFrames.

Considering that the pandas library is installed and that the data are in a `.csv` file (matching the example you provided).

#### 1. import the pandas library and load the data

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

You now have a Pandas Dataframe as follow:

```
    id  year  type  sale
0   1   1998    a   5
1   2   2000    b   10
2   3   1999    c   20
3   4   2001    b   15
4   5   2001    a   25
5   6   1998    b   5
```

#### 2. Plot the "sale" vs "type"

This is easily achieved by:

```
data.plot('type', 'sale', kind='bar')
```

which results in

[image: image1]

If you want the sale for each type to be summed, `data.groupby('type').sum().plot(y='sale', kind='bar')` will do the trick (see #3 for explanation)

#### 3. Plot the "sale" vs "year"

This is basically the same command, except that you have to first sum all the sale in the same year using the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) pandas function.

```
data.groupby('year').sum().plot(y='sale', kind='bar')
```

This will result in

[image: image2]

Edit:

#### 4 Unstack the different type per year

You can also unstack the different 'type' per year for each bar by using groupby on 2 variables

```
data.groupby(['year', 'type']).sum().unstack().plot(y='sale', kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

#### Note:

See the [Pandas Documentation on visualization](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) for more information about achieving the layout you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the groupby function! Where should I add the sorting function (by sale) in the plot? I've tried to sort the data then saved it to a temp DataFrame, but I think there must be a simple way...

Comment: Could you tell me more about how to achieve my second layout? I am trying to do it with two groupby's and add the "stack" option, but I feel I am in the wrong direction...

Comment: I am trying to do is like, df.groupby(['year', 'type']).sum().plot(x='year', y='sale', kind='bar', stacked=True)... I don't have a concrete idea anyway, really appreciate your assistance!!

Comment: @Pandaaaaaaa yes, you're on the right track. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am reading the doc regarding DataFrame unstack and pivot